# Convert string to non string with C macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I know that it is possible to convert something to string with macro like this:

```
#define STRING(s) #s

printf("%s", STRING(i am string));
```

But it is possible to do the opposite?

```
#define MyType(type) ??? 

MyType("uint16_t") myint = 100;
```

Comment: Smells awefuly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You really should **improve your question** (by editing it) to motivate it. I cannot imagine a case where doing what you want is actually useful.

Comment: But how does it know how to convert it from a string to any arbitrary type?  Or will it always be an integer type of some precision?  What about floating point?

Comment: Preprocessor can join tokens together, but it can't break a token, so short answer is NO. However you can create something that might do something similar, but it depends on use case and your problem, but I don't think it is a thing you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible using the standard C preprocessor. What you want is not part of the standard C11 (or C99) language. And neither part of C++11 or C++14 (which is a different language than C).

But you might use some different preprocessor or some script to transform your weird source file into some C file.

You could also perhaps customize your compiler (e.g. with a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension) to add such behavior thru additional builtins or pragmas. That would be very compiler specific, and probably requires more work than what you can afford.

Comment: For completeness: C does do de-stringification as part of `_Pragma`. But that can only be used to form `#pragma` directives so wouldn't help the OP.

Comment: You can calculate arbitrary compile time values from strings with boost::metaparse  so it is possible.

Comment: Probably not in the general case.